# Select top/bottom 50% of a table in Redshift sql query

Tags: amazon-redshift

Using psql (Postgres 12.3.1) running on Windows Server 2019. This server has 64 GB of RAM, and I am attempting to run the following query on an Amazon Redshift database:

```
psql -h amazon-redshift-database.redshift.amazonaws.com -d DATABASE -U USER -p 5439 -a -c "select * from realy.large_table" -F ',' -o "D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\amazon_redshift_download\really.large_table.csv"
```

It errors out with: **"out of memory"** midway through the query. The table contains 458,968,689 rows, with 5 columns: varchar(50), varchar(50), varchar(50), integer, timestamp.

MSSQL seems to have the following ability:

```
"select top 50 percent * from really.large_table ..."
```

Does PostgreSQL have anything similar? If not, is there a way to break my queries into percentages such that I can decrease the size / memory consumption for my query? I've tried performance tuning and using servers with more memory without success.

Version:

```
psql -h amazon-redshift-database.redshift.amazonaws.com -d DATABASE-U USER -p 5439 -a -c "select version();"
 version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.16966
(1 row)
```

Tried:

```
select * from really.large_table tablesample (50)
select * from really.large_table tablesample(50)
select * from really.large_table tablesample (50);
select * from really.large_table tablesample(50);
tablesample system (50)
tablesample system(50)
tablesample system (50);
tablesample system(50);
select * from tablesample system (50); <-with above combinations
```

Result:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "50"
LINE 1: select * from really.large_table tablesample(50)
```

[image]

Comment: In Postgres you can use `select * from really_large_table tablesample (50)` - I have no idea if Redshift supports that as well.

Comment: See above for my attempts.

Comment: Does `tablesample system (50)` or `tablesample system (50)` work?

Comment: "*Using Postgres 12.3.1 running on Windows Server 2019*" contradicts "*run the following query via psql on an **Amazon Redshift** database*"

Comment: Still receiving a syntax error there. Edited my original query to include the full psql syntax, and clarified the statement.

Comment: `tablesample system (50)` **will** work with Postgres. And `psql` is only the client program, not the actual database software and essentially irrelevant to the question). Please add the output of `select version();` to your question

Comment: I have this same issue. My version is **PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.16966**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't the most desirable solution, but it worked for me.

1. Install SQL Workbench/J
2. Download and install the Redshift JDBC driver: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.htm
3. From an administrative command prompt, launch SQL Workbench J with the following Java command (note: 60g = 60GB, set to amount of RAM you'd like to let it use):

   java -Xmx**60g** -jar sqlworkbench.jar
4. When it launches, set "Fetch size" on the homescreen to some X: 10,000 < X < 200,000
5. Connect to your database
6. Use the GUI's Database Explorer to Export Data.
7. Sit back and wait a long time for it to download your large tables

It never consumed much ram when the fetch size is restricted. I believe this to be the key step, rather than giving the application more memory.